# Can a noun have two definite articles?

Tags: articles

Conosco che alcune parole, come "dito", hanno due forme ("dito", "dita") e due significati: possono avere due articoli determinativi?

Per esempio:

> la dita
>
> il dita

Comment: Attenzione: l'articolo determinativo dipende principalmente da genere e numero (nonché, come osserva Gianni Alessandro più giù, dalle lettere iniziali). "Dito" è maschile singolare, quindi vuole "il"; "dita" è femminile plurale, quindi vuole "le". Che io sappia non esiste una parola "dito" di genere femminile così come non esiste una parola "dita" di genere maschile. Come osserva Gianni Alessandro, esistono parole, come "boa", con due significati e generi diversi e che quindi richiedono due diversi articoli.

Comment: Per maggiore chiarezza, aggiungo che "il dita" non esiste: "il dito" diventa al plurale "le dita".

Comment: ...e se è per questo, non esiste neanche “la dita”.

Comment: Probabilmente md nth ha confuso la parola "ditta" con il plurale di dito

Answer (score 14):

In italiano ogni nome appartiene a un genere, maschile o femminile. Alcuni nomi cambiano genere passando dal singolare al plurale, l'esempio più famoso è

> *il carcere*, *le carceri*

e *i carceri* non è comunemente accettato. Più frequente è il doppio genere al plurale:

1. *il braccio*, *le braccia* (del corpo), *i bracci* (in senso figurato);
2. *il dito*, *le dita* (della mano), *i diti* (in senso collettivo);
3. *il muro*, *i muri* (in senso proprio), *le mura* della città.

Ci sono vari altri esempi. Una parola che può avere “doppio genere” è *fila*

1. *la fila* è quella che si fa all'ufficio postale; oppure *la fila indiana* quando si cammina uno dietro l'altro;
2. *le fila* è il plurale di *filo* in senso figurato: si dice *i fili del telefono*, ma *le fila della congiura*.

Questo *le fila* è proprio il plurale di *filo*, perché si pensa alla congiura come “trama di un tessuto”.

Comment: Guarda guarda, se non e` @egreg di tex... Perche' scrivi che *i bracci* vale in senso figurato? Io avrei detto che le braccia ha valore collettivo (allo stesso modo di dita) e indica tutti gli arti superiori di una persona. Invece *i bracci*, cosi` come *i diti* ha valore specifico (oltre che figurato nel caso de *i bracci*). Ad esempio. *Rinvenuta fossa comune a Isernia, alle vittime mancano i bracci destri.* e poi *I diti indici sono quelli maggiormente usati per esplorare le cavita` del corpo umano: meglio evitarli nelle strette di mano* Ciao

Comment: @astabada *I bracci* è più usato in senso figurato che proprio: *bracci meccanici*, *bracci di una prigione*. L'esempio che porti è un po' artificioso, non trovi? Certamente corretto, comunque.

Comment: Artificios *issimo* :)

Comment: Ufficialmente si dicono nomi sovrabbondanti (https://www.lagrammaticaitaliana.it/lezioni/62/nomi-sovrabbondanti#:~:text=Si%20dicono%20sovrabbondanti%20i%20nomi,dei%20casi%20ha%20significato%20diverso.)

Answer (score 7):

Correggo innanzitutto la tua domanda:

> so che alcune parole, come dita, hanno due forme, dita e dito, e due significati. Ma può una sola parola avere due articoli determinativi?

In più ti rispondo:

L'articolo determinativo dipende da come inizia una parola, non dalla sua terminazione. Tra singolare e plurale cambia solo la terminazione, quindi, se anche la parola ha due significati diversi tra singolare e plurale, l'articolo è lo stesso (opportunamente declinato).

Esistono casi dove l'articolo e il significato cambiano per il genere;

Esempio è:

> il boa / la boa
>
> **La boa:** buoy, anchored float used as a guide to navigators.
>
> **Il boa:** boa constrictor, species of snake.

Qui l'articolo cambia, in quanto cambia il genere della parola, e a seconda dell'articolo assume due significati molto differenti.

Ho risolto il tuo dubbio?

Comment: si,e che differenza da il boa,la boa

Comment: @md ho modificato la domanda aggiungendo la definizione. Si tratta di un caso raro, sono poche le parole con differente significato tra maschile e femminile.

Answer (score 6):

La parola "pneumatico" può usare sia l'articolo "lo" ("lo pneumatico" è la forma ritenuta corretta dai puristi) che l'articolo "il" ("il pneumatico" è tollerato). Al plurale similmente si ha "gli pneumatici / i pneumatici".

Poi a Cremona nessuno direbbe "lo gnocco fritto" ma "il gnocco fritto", ma non lo scriverei mai in un tema a scuola :-)

Comment: Non direi *gli gnocchi* nemmeno sotto tortura. ;-) Né mangerei mai *lo gnocco fritto*.

Comment: @egreg: decisamente a Milano senti dire più spesso *lo gnocco / gli gnocchi*. In ogni caso, se non lo vuoi lo gnocco fritto lo prendo io!

Comment: @egreg: puoi dire quello che vuoi (per esempio io non direi mai *lo pneumatico*) ma la grammatica è chiara: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/gnocco-lo-o-il_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/

Comment: Sull'articolo per "pneumatico", sia la [Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/pneumatico-pneumatico) che la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pneumatico-il-o-lo_(La_grammatica_italiana)/) concordano con la regola riportata da mau.

Comment: @mau: secondo il sottoscritto (che invece trova cacofonico e impronunciabile “il pneumatico”), così è un po' barare: è come dire che il pronome “gli” è sia maschile che femminile...

Comment: per me barare sarebbe affermare che "li" (il modo arcaico per scrivere una data, "li 14 febbraio 2014") sia un articolo... Nel caso di pneumatico c'è un nome che accetta due articoli determinativi maschili singolari, anche se per un rilassamento della grammatica

Comment: @mau: ho detto “secondo il sottoscritto”, che ha le sue idiosincrasie... Ma “li” in “li 14 febbraio”, se non è un articolo, che cos'è? È lo stesso “li” di «Tornate a riveder li vostri liti» (Dante) e infiniti altri luoghi della storia dell'italiano.

Comment: Nel modenese, se dici "lo gnocco" ti guardano moolto male! "il" gnocco ha una chiara derivazione dialettale, ma è talmente in uso da essere considerato corretto oramai anche a scuola.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few different ways the same (orthographic) word can take two different gendered articles:

#### Homographs

Some non-cognate words of distinct genders are coincidentally spelled identically:

- *il boa* / *la boa*
- *il lama* / *la lama*

others are cognate but have different genders for different (often related) definitions:

- *il fine* / *la fine*
- *il rosa* / *la rosa*

#### Ambiguous gender (persons)

Words that refer to persons which take different articles depending on the sex of the referent:

**ambiguous in singular and plural:**

- *il / la burocrate, il / la cartomante*
- *il / la cantante*, *lo / la amante* (*gli / le amanti*)
- *il / la consorte, lo / la erede, il / la custode*, *il / la testimone* (*i / le testimoni*)
- *lo / la incurabile; lo / la abruzzese, il / la contabile, il / la francese* (*i / le contabili, i / le francesi*)

**ambiguous in singular but inflected for plural:**

- *il / la collega*, *lo / la atleta* (*gli atleti / le atlete*)
- *lo / la artista, il / la finalista, il / la pianista* (*i pianisti / le pianiste*)
- *lo / la omicida, il / la pediatra, lo / la astronauta* (*i pediatri / le pediatre, gli astronauti / le astronaute*)

A group of a few words with the prefix *capo-*, that the masculine plural form the inner plural in *-i-* , but that the feminine plural is invariable:

- *il / la capofamiglia*, *il / la capostazione* (*i capistazione / le capostazione*)

**Abbreviations:**

Inflected forms which lose their inflections through abbreviation but retain their gender:

- *Fede* (*Federico* / *Federica*)
- *Robi*, *Roby* (*Roberto* / *Roberta*)
- *Ale*, *Alex* (*Alessandro* / *Alessandra*)
- *il / la sub* «*il subacqueo* / *la subacquea*»
- *il / la prof* «*il professore* / *la professoressa*»

And related, but lexically distinct words with the same abbreviation:

- *la tele* «televisione» / *il tele* «teleobiettivo»

**Historically male professions**

Those ending *-a* remain unchanged when referring to female persons:

- *la guardia*, *la sentinella*, *la recluta*

But those ending *-o* (e.g. *il soprano*, *il contralto*), when referring to female persons, may cause oscillations in the agreement, responding either to the grammatical gender of the word:

> - *il soprano è andato via con suo marito*

or to the sex of the person:

> - *il soprano è andata via con suo marito*
> - *la soprano è andata via con suo marito*
>     <sup>(**Note:** this form may be incorrect in many dialects but sees occasional use: [1](http://docplayer.it/3742060-Il-genere-femminile-nell-italiano-di-oggi-norme-e-uso.html) [2](http://donnealpha.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/conguaglio-linguistico.html))</sup>

Some of these *-o* terminal words have additionally developed inflected female forms which may be used:

- *il/la ministro* / *la ministra*
- *il/la chirurgo* / *la chirurga*
- *il/la vigile*

#### Epicene nouns (animals)

Some animal names are masculine or feminine, regardless of the sex of the specific animal referred to:

- *il dromedario, il falco, lo ippopotamo*
- *la balena, la giraffa, la scimmia*

#### Latin Neuter

Some words in Italian have vestigial traits of the Latin neuter gender. These words take masculine articles in the singular and feminine (or masculine) in the plural (reinterpreting the Latin neuter plural suffix *-a* as feminine).

- *l'uovo* / *le uova* ("the egg(s)")
- *l'osso* / *le ossa* or *gli ossi* ("the bone(s)")
- *il braccio* / *le braccia* or *i bracci* ("the arm(s)")
- *il ginocchio* / *le ginocchia* or *i ginocchi* ("the knee(s)")
- *il sopracciglio* / *le sopracciglia* or *i sopraccigli* ("the eyebrow(s)")

Note that for some of these, the choice of plural gender changes the meaning:

- **Body parts**
  Sometimes, for body parts, the feminine/neuter plural denotes the literal meaning while the masculine one denotes a figurative meaning:

  - *il braccio* ("the arm") / *le braccia* ("the arms") / *i bracci* ("the isthmuses", "the inlets")
  - *il corno* ("the horn") / *le corna* ("the horns" of an animal) / *i corni* ("the horns" as musical instruments)
- **Poetic/Old fashioned usage**
  Sometimes, especially in poetic and old-fashioned Italian, the masculine plural acts as a count noun, while the neuter/feminine plural acts as a mass noun:

  - *il cervello* ("the brain") / *due cervelli* ("two brains") / *le cervella* ("the cerebral matter")
  - *l'anello* ("the ring") / *due anelli* ("two rings") / *le anella* ("ringlets")
  - *il dito* ("the finger") / *due dita* ("two fingers")  / *le dita* ("the fingers") / *i diti indici* ("the index fingers")

#### Loanwords

Loanwords often oscillate between masculine and feminine, either remaining truly ambiguous or settling at some point on a standard gender:

- *e-mail*, *autoblindo*, *automobile* (used as either masc. or fem. for ~30 years after its introduction)

---

<sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_grammar#Nouns</sup>
<sup>http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-ambigeneri_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29</sup>
<sup>http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Italian/Grammar/Nouns/Italian-Nouns-Different_gender_and_meanings.html</sup>

Comment: Very good job with the long and clear answer, but there are a few points that should be fixed: 1) _sentinella_ and the like are just feminine nouns (with article _la_) regardless of the sex of the person they refer to; 2) _soprano_, symmetrically, is simply a masculine name (always _il soprano_); 3) there are no words in Italian that “are neither masculine nor feminine”; those are the only two genders in Italian, regardless of the Latin words the words come from.

Comment: @DaG Ah, thanks - will correct those points.

Answer (score 1):

L'osso, le ossa (del corpo umano), gli ossi (di animale, ad esempio il pollo arrosto ha gli ossi).

Comment: questi sono due plurali diversi (e per quanto mi riguarda "le ossa" è una vestigia di genere neutro), non due articoli diversi per la stessa forma.